# Load Angular 4 project with RequireJS

Tags: angular, requirejs

I am trying to build Angular4 application using ng command.

I can build and run using ng serve.

I want to load that Angular4 application to load/run with RequireJS. I have search a lots but can't find any tutorial. Below is sample:-

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
require.config({
paths: {
'vendor':'vendor.eabc4b1001d9d0dc5a72',
'polyfills':'polyfills.eabc4b1001d9d0dc5a72',
'app':'app.eabc4b1001d9d0dc5a72',
'styles':'styles.eabc4b1001d9d0dc5a72'
         }
  });
</script>
```

Kindly suggest workaround and provide some tutorial to overcome this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you expect the thing to work? You're already building the application to a single file with Webpack. What's the role of RequireJS here? You will have problems with finding such tutorial because this setup doesn't make much sense so far.

Comment: @estus , yes u r correct, I can build angular with webpack. But I want to embed in other application which module loader is using RequireJS and since my angular4 build doesn't loaded with RequireJS then I can't able to run in RequireJS environment.

Comment: The output of `ng build` is JS file. You can use it with RequireJS as any other.

Comment: @estus, can I have some tutorial to configure with requirejs on this webpack app => https://v4.angular.io/generated/zips/webpack/webpack.zip . Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if such tutorial exists (requesting for tutorials is off-topic on SO). It doesn't matter if it's raw Webpack or Angular CLI. They both compile the app to a single file. This file should be used as RequireJS module, as any other JS file. I don't see any problems with this approach, but consider re-asking the question with your current attempt and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if there will be certain problems and errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution at last, since 'ng build' uses webpack to build files under dist folder and minified its output library by putting webpackJsonp which is not known/imported by lagacy javascript applications. I have created webpack config and remove new 'webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin' so that it builds as simple js file for all the vendor.js,main.js,polyfill.js and these files now easily loaded/imported by lagacy javascript application. Thanks.

Below is the webpack common sample :-

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        // 'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
        'styles': './src/styles.scss'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },

    resolveLoader: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            // loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('./src', 'app'),
            // loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader', 'to-string-loader']
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        },  
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
           use: [
                { loader: "to-string-loader"},
                { loader: "to-string" },
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ]
      },

      ]
    },

    plugins: [
    // comment code so that webpack generate simple js file output <====
       // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //    name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
     //   }),

      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
        {} // a map of your routes
      ),

      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, helpers.root('./src')
      ), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20357


        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```